# AVX Vectorized Multi-threaded Mandelbrot Renderer

Tags: c++, performance, vectorization, simd

I wrote a Mandelbrot renderer in C++ that uses AVX intrinsics to calculate 8 pixels per thread in parallel. It can compute 1080p frames with 256 max iterations in about 40 milliseconds on a 2 core 4 thread i5-6200U laptop. Any advice on performance, code style etc would be appreciated.

https://github.com/voldemoriarty/Qbrot

**The code**:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

#include "EasyBMP.hpp"

struct ColorScheme {
  EasyBMP::RGBColor mapping [16];

  ColorScheme () {
    mapping[0].SetColor(66, 30, 15);
    mapping[1].SetColor(25, 7, 26);
    mapping[2].SetColor(9, 1, 47);
    mapping[3].SetColor(4, 4, 73);
    mapping[4].SetColor(0, 7, 100);
    mapping[5].SetColor(12, 44, 138);
    mapping[6].SetColor(24, 82, 177);
    mapping[7].SetColor(57, 125, 209);
    mapping[8].SetColor(134, 181, 229);
    mapping[9].SetColor(211, 236, 248);
    mapping[10].SetColor(241, 233, 191);
    mapping[11].SetColor(248, 201, 95);
    mapping[12].SetColor(255, 170, 0);
    mapping[13].SetColor(204, 128, 0);
    mapping[14].SetColor(153, 87, 0);
    mapping[15].SetColor(106, 52, 3);
  }

  EasyBMP::RGBColor Color (int itr) {
    return mapping[itr % 16];
  }
};

template <class CS = ColorScheme>
struct MandelbrotMultiThreaded {
  int height;
  int width;
  int max;

  float xres;
  float yres;
  float x0, y0;
  float xl, yl, yh;

  CS cs;

  void Configure (
    int   height, 
    int   width,
    int   max = 128,
    float xl = -2.5,
    float xh = 1,
    float yl = -1,
    float yh = 1 
  ) {
    this->x0      = xl;
    this->y0      = yl;
    this->xl      = xl;
    this->yl      = yl;
    this->yh      = yh;
    this->xres    = (xh - xl) / width;
    this->yres    = (yh - yl) / height;
    this->max     = max;
    this->width   = width;
    this->height  = height;
  }

  void LineRenderer (int i, EasyBMP::Image *buff) {
    using fvec_t = __m256;
    using ivec_t = __m256i;

    fvec_t x0 = _mm256_add_ps(_mm256_set1_ps(xl), _mm256_setr_ps(0, xres, 2*xres, 3*xres, 4*xres, 5*xres, 6*xres, 7*xres));
    fvec_t y0 = _mm256_set1_ps((i) * yres - yh);

    for (int xc = 0; xc < width; xc += 8) {
      ivec_t itr  = _mm256_setzero_si256();
      fvec_t x    = _mm256_setzero_ps();
      fvec_t y    = _mm256_setzero_ps();
      fvec_t ab   = _mm256_setzero_ps();

      fvec_t aCmp = _mm256_setzero_ps();
      ivec_t iCmp = _mm256_setzero_si256();
      int aMask = 0xff, iMask = 0;

      while ((aMask & (~iMask & 0xff)) != 0) {
        auto xx   = _mm256_mul_ps(x, x);
        auto yy   = _mm256_mul_ps(y, y);
        auto xyn  = _mm256_mul_ps(x, y);
        auto xy   = _mm256_add_ps(xyn, xyn);
        auto xn   = _mm256_sub_ps(xx, yy);
        ab        = _mm256_add_ps(xx, yy);
        y         = _mm256_add_ps(xy, y0);
        x         = _mm256_add_ps(xn, x0);
        aCmp      = _mm256_cmp_ps(ab, _mm256_set1_ps(4), _CMP_LT_OQ);
        iCmp      = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(itr, _mm256_set1_epi32(max));
        aMask     = _mm256_movemask_ps(aCmp) & 0xff;
        iMask     = _mm256_movemask_ps((fvec_t)iCmp) & 0xff;

        // only add one to the iterations of those whose ab < 4 and itr < max
        // aCmp = 1 for ab < 4
        // iCmp = 0 for itr < max
        auto inc  = _mm256_andnot_ps((fvec_t)iCmp, aCmp);
        // inc = -1 for (itr < max) & (ab < 4)
        // itr = itr - inc [- (-1) = + 1]
        itr       = _mm256_sub_epi32(itr, (ivec_t)inc);
      }

      x0 = _mm256_add_ps(x0, _mm256_set1_ps(8*xres));
      // collect results and update buffer
      int res[8] __attribute__ ((aligned));
      _mm256_store_si256((ivec_t*)res, itr);
      for (int c = 0; c < 8; ++c) {
        buff->SetPixel(xc + c, i, cs.Color(res[c]));
      }
    }
  }

  void RenderMultiThreaded (EasyBMP::Image *buff) {
    // use openMP to handle threading for us
    // tell the compiler to create a task queue
    // it is faster because different sections of the set take different time
    // so dynamic scheduling performs better than static
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
      LineRenderer(y, buff);
    }
  }

  auto RenderWithTime (EasyBMP::Image *buff, int runs = 1) {
    // find the number of available threads
    const int pars = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    std::cout << "Using " << pars << " threads\n";

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    while (runs--) RenderMultiThreaded(buff);
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto dur = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end-start).count();
    return dur;
  }
};

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

  int w = 640;
  int h = 480;
  int M = 128;
  int C = 1;

  float xl = -2.5;
  float xh = 1;
  float yl = -1;
  float yh = 1;

  if (argc >= 3) {
    w = atoi(argv[1]);
    h = atoi(argv[2]);
  }

  if (argc >= 4) {
    M = atoi(argv[3]);
  }

  if (argc >= 5) {
    C = atoi(argv[4]);
  }

  EasyBMP::Image bmp (w, h, "render.bmp");
  MandelbrotMultiThreaded<ColorScheme> mb;
  mb.Configure(h,w,M,xl,xh,yl,yh);

  auto dur = mb.RenderWithTime(&bmp, C);

  std::cout << 
    "Rendering done\n"
    "Avg time: " 
    << (dur / C) * 1e-6 << " (ms)\n"
    "Tot time: "
    << dur * 1e-6 << " (ms)\n";

  bmp.Write();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You made significant changes to your question after you received an answer, and those changes invalidated that answer.  You should not change the code in your question after it gets answered.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).  If you want the changes to your code reviewed, ask a new followup question (linking back to this one).

Comment: @s.s.anne, you should be able to fix the stray `\`\`\`` just by adding a blank line (or HTML comment) after the code block.

Comment: @TobySpeight Oh. That's odd. There was a space there before but apparently that didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 8):

There are some `& 0xff` operations that are not necessary:

- `(aMask & (~iMask & 0xff))`, because the bits reset by `& 0xff` are already zero in `aMask`, so they never survive the "main" `&`.
- `_mm256_movemask_ps(...) & 0xff`, because `vmovmskps` can only set the low 8 bits, the upper bits are already zero.

> ```
>     // inc = -1 for (itr < max) & (ab < 4)
>     // itr = itr - inc [- (-1) = + 1]
>     itr       = _mm256_sub_epi32(itr, (ivec_t)inc);
> ```

This is good, sometimes people focus too much on adding 1 and overlook the possibility of subtracting -1 but you didn't fall into that trap.

This part though:

> `(ivec_t)inc`

That doesn't work with MSVC, nor does the earlier `(fvec_t)iCmp`. `_mm256_castps_si256` (and related intrinsics) work though, which all do nothing but just change the type. Admittedly that's more of a mouthful than just casting, and it makes no difference for GCC and Clang.

Comment: I use `(~iMask & 0xff)` because `~` will set the upper bits high.

Comment: `_mm256_castps_si256` aah, I didn't have MSVC to test with. Well I'll change it. Thanks for the tip